# install4j's downloadable component resume downloading

Tags: install4j, resume-download

I have an install4j's v7 project, with downloadable components.
Our clients are on rural areas with poor internet connection, with intermittent connections.

After the connection is lost, the user has to retry and the component is downloaded from the start every time, it doesn't download only the remaining bytes, as a browser does.

Is there a way to configure resumable downloads for a downloadable component?

Currently we publish both online and full versions of our installers, with all the downloadable components already present, as the browser resumes OK the download of such full installers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 9.0.5, this is not a feature that is supported by install4j. I have added this to our issue tracker.