# does install4j's download file action has the capability to pause and resume the download in version 10?

Tags: install4j, resume-download

I want my users to be able to pause and resume where the file download left off during installation since we are managing really big files (a few GB) so if the user wants to pause and resume he can.

I'm currently using the 'Download file' action under 'Display Progress' screen.

I see that there is a similar question but the answer [install4j's downloadable component resume downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70127087/install4js-downloadable-component-resume-downloading/) was from version 9.0.5, is this capability available for version 10?

Thanks!

I tried to find this capability Out of the box in the action's configuration, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, install4j 10 does not have this feature.

Comment: Thanks Ingo! I'll try to do custom code.